# GWT Requestfactory entity locator does not work with Objectify when the Entity has Long id

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, objectify

My GWT+GAE app uses Requestfactroy entity locator and at the server side i use Objectify, it works well when my Entity ID type is String, now i want to change to Long id, and stuck: by using the locator signature i can not find the entity:

```
 @Override
    public T find( Class<? extends T> clazz, Long id )
    {
    }
```

Because Objectify requires @Parent key included to fetch the sub-entities(HRD), and from the method above we can not get the parent.
I found this thread from GWT forum:
[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/requestfactory%2420don%27t%2420allow%2420appengine%2420parent%2420relationship/google-web-toolkit/OmxjBgBbFhU/LtZYV7iWa90J)

However this thread seems didn't give any constructive suggestions(it falls back to String ID Entity finally for the solution).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the long ID is not enough to identify your object. As you say, you also need its parent, so the ID is actually a compound ID: the parent object, and the child's ID.

BTW, what's the problem with using the `keyToString` or similar here? (as suggested on the thread you link to)
The ID from a `Locator` is only used on the server-side and only *by* the locator (and serialized *as-is* to be passed back and forth to/from the client; but they're opaque things on the client-side, that you aren't even given access).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I use KeyFactory's keyToString and StringToKey when i using String ID entity and it works fine, so you means i can keep using the String typed locator at server side with long id entity? i'll try.

Comment: As you said, the id in the entity has no relation to the id in the locator, the later is just a compound thing, my test passed and many thanks!